# In React DevTools my component is re-rendering but the parent is not, and it's state/props are not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React App that is currently re-rendering more often than I'd like. I'm using React DevTools Profiler to record my session and I have the option checked to record why the components re-render.

For the component in question, under 'Why did this component render?' it says 'The parent component rendered.' However in the component tree of the devtools, none of the parent components are rendering. They all say 'Did not render during this profiling session.' The component I'm troubleshooting is basically the highest level component in the actual project.

Above it are the following components:

App

BrowserRouter

Router

Context.Provider

Switch

Context.Consumer

Route

Context.Consumer

Context.Provider

MyComponent

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example application that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The component is most likely being re-rendered due to a change in context, and the React DevTools isn't reporting this accurately.

See https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/17068 for some more detail on the DevTool reporting in this situation.

Comment: Any progress on this? Makes the result pretty tough to interpret without when debugging non-refresh issues right? Or am I not using it right?